# Python sys.path.append

Tags: python

I am doing some multiprocessing work on python which isn't doable from a jupyter notebook. I have written the required functions in a .py file and I'm now importing it into my notebook.

How do I import this directly from the same folder without specifying the directory of where the file is in? This needs to be run-able on different PCs when sent to other people and thus I dont want to append the system path for my computer specifically.

```
import sys
#sys.path.append to get
sys.path.append()
from map_reducer import *
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: wildcard subset import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226390/python-wildcard-subset-import)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import them with:

```
from FileNameWithOutTheDotPy import *
```

And then just run them like normal:

```
FunctionThatDoesStuff(var1,var2)
```

***Note:*** They do need to be in the same directory for this to work.